# Pull logs from remote server into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

The short question is: Is it possible to pull logs (within logfiles) from a remote server and ingest them into the ELK stack.

The long story is the following:

- We have a setup with a `DMZ` which is publically facing
- We have an `intranet` environment which hosts alot of internal systems, including the ELK stack
- Due to security regulations we cannot establish connections (on IP level) from the `DMZ` towards the `intranet`.
- We can however establish connections from the `intranet` towards the `DMZ`

Due to this setup, we cannot follow the normal route of installing a `Filebeat` on the server where the logs are stored and push the messages towards our `logstash` installation.

What we would like to do is something that looks somewhat like the following:

- Filebeat or any other process gathers the logs on the server inside the `DMZ`
- On this server there is some process (`Filebeat`, `logstash`, another `elasticsearch` instance?) which keeps those information in a local store
- This tool (whatever it might be in the end) listens on a port which is available from the `intranet`
- Another tool inside the `intranet` connects to the `DMZ` tool and pulls all gathered logs for further processing.

Our investigations sofar only resulted in solutions which push the log information to either `logstash` or `elasticsearch`.

One thing we do not want to do is to use fileshares to make the logfiles available directly from the `intranet`.

Our question is whether what we have in mind is possible at all and if so, what tools and with which setup we would accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following using Kafka as a message broker

On your `DMZ` server you will have filebeat collecting logs and sending to a logstash instance, this logstash instace will then output your logs to kafka.

It is a simple pipeline with a `beats` input, your fitlers and a `kafka` output, if you don't want to do any enrichments on your data, you can send your logs direct to kafka from filebeat.

Your kafka broker will then listen on a port and wait for any consumer to connect and consumes the messages.

On your `intranet` you will need a logstash instance with a pipeline using the `kafka` input, this pipeline will act as a kafka consumer and will pull your messages, you can then use the `elasticsearch` output to store then in your `intranet` elasticsearch cluster.

For more information read the [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart), and the documentation for the [kafka input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html) and [kafka output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html) in the logstash documentation.

Comment: Kafka is a nice workaround for this. It will require an additional piece of infrastructure, but I guess that is the tradeoff we have to take. Thanks for the hint! (I found another solution which is pretty much the same way to go, just using another elasticsearch instance to buffer the messages). But I like the Kafka way more, it feels like less configuration / setup footprint than another elasticsearch install.